# Does your team rating get taken into account in FUTs opponent selection?

Tags: fifa-18

In FIFA Ultimate Team (FUT) you can select players from different skill levels and leagues and people usually use the best players they can get their hands on, which of course makes sense.

But what happens if you select only players from your own or favorite team from a lower division, where all your players end up being silver or bronze? You would still have a proper morale, but a much lower rating (~65-70 instead of ~85). Do you get opponents doing the same or still the same high rating opponents? Does it even matter at all what team rating you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No.

EA won't disclose how exactly their matchmaking works, but according to some reading the squad strength does not matter at all. The only factors are the people themselves:

- Division
- ELO Rating
- Location (opponents close to you are preferred over others)
- Time (if hardly anyone is online you'll hardly get matched against someone at your level)